# Find and Replace in Visual Studio with Regex

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-2015

I have an XSL file that I need to replace all the classes with a single class.  Example:

`class="class1"`, `class="anotherclass"`, `class="yoyoclass"`

and replace all the values between the quotes with `NewClass`.

Answer (score 1):

**Find:**

```
class=".*?"
```

**Replace:**

```
class="NewClass"
```

**Explanation:**

The replacement is self-explanatory, since it is the same for all classes.  The only part of the find regex which needs explanation is the `.*?` term.  Here, the `?` tells the regex to stop consuming upon hitting the *first* closing quotes.  Try removing the `?` and you will see that the regex will become greedy and match everything until the *last* quote.